# Import JSON data in to array in REACTJS

Tags: json, reactjs, ecmascript-6, jsx

So ive been looking at this for a couple hours now trying to get my head around it but I just cant figure it out.

I have a json file located at '/src/data/topbar.json' which i want to include in my topbar-container component which will be used to generate the top menu.

What am I doing wrong here?

topbar.json:

```
{
  "topbarLinks": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "icon": "header__topbar__list__link__icon glyphicon glyphicon-home",
      "text": "home",
      "link": "/"
     },
     {
      "id": 2,
      "icon": "header__topbar__list__link__icon glyphicon glyphicon-euro",
      "text": "Pricing",
      "link": "/pricing"
     },
     {
      "id": 3,
      "icon": "header__topbar__list__link__icon glyphicon glyphicon-exclamation-sign",
      "text": "Help",
      "link": "/help"
     },
     {
      "id": 4,
      "icon": "header__topbar__list__link__icon glyphicon glyphicon-question-sign",
      "text": "FAQ",
      "link": "/faq"
     },
     {
      "id": 5,
      "icon": "header__topbar__list__link__icon glyphicon glyphicon-edit",
      "text": "Register",
      "link": "/register"
     },
     {
      "id": 6,
      "icon": "header__topbar__list__link__icon glyphicon glyphicon-share",
      "text": "Login",
      "link": "/login"
     }
  ]
}
```

topbar-container.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import './topbar-container.scss';
import Link from '../topbar-link/topbar-link';
require ('../../data/topbar.json');

class TopbarContainer extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.State = {
      topbarLinks: []
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch('../../data/topbar.json')
      .then(results => {
        return results.json();
      }).then(data => {
        let topbarLinks = data.results.map((topbarLinks, key) => {
          return (
            <Link
              key={topbarLinks.id}
              text={topbarLinks.text}
              icon={topbarLinks.icon}
              link={topbarLinks.link}
            />
          )
        })
      })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container-fluid header__topbar">
        <div className="row">
          <div className="container">
            <ul className="header__topbar__list">
              {this.state.topbarLinks}
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default TopbarContainer;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't fetch a local JSON file, you either have to import it, or setup a webserver that will serve that JSON file

```
import myJson from '../../data/topbar.json';
```

Then just map over it and don't forget to setState

```
componentDidMount() {
    let topbarLinks = myJson.topbarLinks.map((topbarLinks, key) => {
      return (
        <Link
          key={topbarLinks.id}
          text={topbarLinks.text}
          icon={topbarLinks.icon}
          link={topbarLinks.link}
        />
      )
    })
    this.setState({topbarLinks: topbarLinks});  // <--
    //or just this.setState({ topbarLinks });
  }
```

and as somebody else noted this.state has to be lowercase

Comment: this sends back the following error: Line 32:  'topbarLinks' is not defined  no-undef

Comment: console.log topbarLinks to see what it returns before assigning it to state

Comment: it sends back an undefined error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'topbarLinks' of null

Comment: try data.topbarLinks.map instead of data.results.map

Comment: still doesnt work. error: 'topbarLinks' is not defined  no-undef

Comment: what do you see when you console.log(data)

Comment: @MarkHughes88 - Change this.State to this.state in constructor

Answer (score 1):

topbar.json:

```
export default {
  "topbarLinks": []
}
```

then you can simply import it without fetch

```
import data from '../../data/topbar.json'
let topbarLinks = data.results.map((topbarLinks, key) => {
  return (
;
```

Answer (score 0):

Change map function to data.topbarLinks.map to access json data.

```
let topbarLinks = data.topbarLinks.map((topbarLinks, key) => {
      return (
        <Link
          key={topbarLinks.id}
          text={topbarLinks.text}
          icon={topbarLinks.icon}
          link={topbarLinks.link}
        />
      )
    })
```

And then set state

```
this.setState({topbarLinks: topbarLinks});
```

Change your initial state as this.State to this.state in constructor.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that State should be capitalized in this.State in your constructor.